# What normative text governs that a friend defined in-class can be found by non-ADL lookup only once (re-)declared in the enclosing namespace?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function, name-lookup

<sub>*All standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

A function declared as a friend can also be *defined* at the friend declaration as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
struct A {
    // Definition of 'a::foo()' 
    friend void foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }   
};
}  // namespace a
```

Such a function as `a::foo()`, sometimes referred to as a "hidden friend" cannot be found by means of unqualified or qualified lookup:

```
int main() {
    a::foo();  // error: no member named 'foo' in namespace 'a'
}
```

whereas, as per [[basic.lookup.argdep]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep#4) it can be found, however, via ADL [**emphasis** mine]:

> When considering an *associated namespace*, the lookup is the same as
> the lookup performed when the associated namespace is used as a
> qualifier ([namespace.qual]) except that:
>
> - [...]
> - **Any namespace-scope friend functions** or friend function templates **declared in associated classes are visible within their
>   respective namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary
>   lookup** ([class.friend]).
> - [...]

specifically based on ADL on the class type in which it has been defined:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
struct A {
    friend void foo(const A&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }   
};
}  // namespace a

int main() {
    foo(a::A{});  // void a::foo(const a::A &)
}
```

However, if we (re-)declare the function in the namespace scope of the class in which it was defined, it can be found via qualified/unqualified lookup:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
struct A {
    friend void foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }   
};
void foo();
}  // namespace a

int main() {
    a::foo();  // void a::foo()
}
```

#### Question

- What normative text governs that a friend defined in-class can be found by non-ADL lookup only once (re-)declared in the enclosing namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below, unless explicitly noted otherwise, refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

#### Friend declarations (definition or not) does not introduce new names into the enclosing namespace

[[class.friend]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.friend#6) governs the scope of a "hidden friend" (only declared and defined at its friend declaration) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **[class.friend]/6:** A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class ([class.local]), the function name is unqualified, **and the function has namespace scope.**

Thus, even if the definition of the function is located at its friend declaration, the friend function has namespace scope and can be explicitly exposed to regular lookup by (re-)declaration in the enclosing namespace (of the class in which it is defined).

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
struct A {
    // Definition of 'a::foo()' (note the namespace scope).
    friend void foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }   
};

// (re-)declaration of foo().
void foo();
}  // namespace 'a'

int main() {
    a::foo();  // void a::foo()
}
```

The more general and interesting question to ask is, however

- What governs that a friend declaration does **not introduce/bind the name** of the declaration **to the namespace scope?**

Which is governed by [[namespace.memdef]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.memdef#3)

> **[namespace.memdef]/3:** **If a friend declaration** in a non-local class **first declares a** class, **function**, class template or function template **the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace**. The friend declaration **does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup** ([basic.lookup.unqual]) **or qualified lookup** ([basic.lookup.qual]). [ *Note:* **The name of the friend will be visible in its namespace if a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope** (either before or after the class definition granting friendship).  *— end note* ] [...]

Thus, it is not relevant here that the function is *defined* at the friend declaration, but rather that a friend declaration (even when not containing a definition) does not introduce the name into the namespace scope; in the following example lookup similarly fails to find the name from the friend declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {
struct A {
    friend void bar(); 
};
}  // namespace 'a'

int main() {
    a::bar();  // error: no member named 'bar' in namespace 'a'
}
```

---

We may also note that the C++20 draft, [N4861](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/) (*March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS*) has added a paragraph, albeit non-normative, that explicitly mentions this; from [[basic.scope.pdecl]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.scope.pdecl#13) [**emphasis** mine]:

> [ Note: Friend declarations refer to functions or classes that are **members of the nearest enclosing namespace**, but they **do not introduce new names into that namespace** ([namespace.memdef]). [...]